# Understand the utility of mocks with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I can't understand at all the utility of mockings. See, I have the next module:

```
function Code() {
  this.generate = () => {
    const result = 'code124';
    return result;
  };
}

module.exports = Code;
```

Now, I want to test it with jest:

```
const Code = require('../lib/code');

jest.mock('../lib/code', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      generate: () => [1, 2, 3]
    };
  });
});

describe('Code', () => {
  test('returns the code "code123"', () => {
    const code = new Code();
    expect(code.generate()).toBe('code123');
  });
});
```

So... This test will be fine but... My code ain't so... what's the point about mocking if I can set a correct result even though my code is wrong?

Comment: not sure if I follow the question. in general while you are testing one module you better mock all its dependencies. in your sample there are no dependencies so you have nothing to mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **NOT** supposed to mock the unit you're testing. You're supposed to mock it's dependencies.

for example:

whenever you have a dependency in the implementation:

```
const dependency = require('dependency');

function Code() {
  this.generate = () => {
    const result = 'code' + dependency.getNumber();
    return result;
  };
}

module.exports = Code;
```

you'll be able to modify it's results to be able to test all scenarios without using the actual implementation of your dependency:

```
const dependency = require('dependency');
const Code = require('../lib/code');
jest.mock('dependency');

describe('Code', () => {

    describe('when dependency returns 123', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        dependency.getNumber.mockReturnValue('123');
      });

      it('should generate code123', () => {
        const code = new Code();
        expect(code.generate()).toEqual('code123');
      });
    });

    describe('when dependency returns 124', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        dependency.getNumber.mockReturnValue('124');
      });

      it('should generate code123', () => {
        const code = new Code();
        expect(code.generate()).toEqual('code124');
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: That makes more sense to me. All the of the guides that I see about mocking do the kind of stuff I did and it makes no sense to me. Thanks a lot!